# int cannot be dereferenced error

Tags: java

I have the int cannot be dereferenced error in the below code where I have //error is here.  I'm confused because the variable b is used to reference a spot in the empl array later in the line without showing as an error.  So how do I fix this and why is it generating an error?
I would appreciate any help.  Example code would be great too as that seems to be the way I learn best.  Thanks!

```
public static void bubbleSort(Employee[] empl) {
    for (int a = 1; a < empl.length; a++) 
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < empl.length - a; b++) 
        {
            if (((empl[b].//error is here
                    getEmployeeNumber()).compareTo
                   ((empl[b + 1].getEmployeeNumber()))) > 0) 
            {
               // swap employees[b] with employees[b+1]
               Employee temp = empl[b];
               empl[b] = empl[b + 1];
               empl[b + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Any other suggestions for sorting the array by Employee Number are welcome.

Comment: empl should not be empty, also empl.lenth-a should be a positive integer

Comment: @MarcB yes there will be a empl[0] entry when the array is populated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getEmployeeNumber()` apparently returns an `int`.

`int` is a primitive type, not an object.
Therefore, you cannot call methods like `compareTo()` on it.

Comment: Yes, getEmployeeNumber() returns an int.  What I dont understand is that empl[b] gives an error while empl[b+1] does not.  Also, I used this same code without error where I switched getEmployeeNumber with getLastName to compare two strings.

Comment: It encounters the `empl[b]` element before it encounters the `empl[b+1]` element, so it would make sense that it would spout out this error first. You can not invoke methods on unboxed primitive types! Why not just compare the integers as... integers, instead of using `compareTo()`?

Comment: @user1690240 Well, `String`s are real objects and have a `.compareTo()`, ints don't. And `empl[b+1]` doesn't give an error because you don't dereference it.