# bmi calculator error float cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java

I am making a simple BMI calculator with a separate test main. I keep getting a *"float cannot be dereferenced"* message when I try to compile. I am relatively new to to coding what am I doing wrong?

```
public class BMI {
    private String name;
    private static float height; //meters
    private static float mass; //kilograms

    public BMI(String n, float h, float m) {
        name = n;
        height = h;
        mass = m;
    }

    public static float getBMI() {
        return (mass / height.pow(2));
    }

    public String toString() {
        return (name + "is" + height + "tall and is " + mass + "and has a BMI of" + getBMI());
    }
}
```

Comment: `height.pow(2)` ... ? Not even `Float` has such a method.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549547/int-cannot-be-dereferenced-error?rq=1

Comment: You probably do *not* want to declare height and mass as `static`.  `static means that all `BMI` objects share the same value for height and the same value for mass.

Answer (score 1):

You can't say `height.pow(2)` (because `float` is a primitive, and because that functionality is in the [`Math`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) utility class). You could use [`Math.pow(double, double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-) like

```
return (mass / Math.pow(height, 2));
```

**or** use simple multiplication (because n<sup>2</sup> == n * n)

```
return (mass / (height * height));
```

Also, in `toString` I would prefer [`String.format(String, Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) over creating many temporary `String`(s) - and I recommend you use the `@Override` annotation to provide additional compile time safety. Something like,

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s is %.2f tall, has mass of %.2f "
            + "and a BMI of %.2f", name, height, mass, getBMI());
}
```

#### And fields should not be `static`

```
private static float height; //meters
private static float mass; //kilograms
```

should *almost certainly* be

```
private float height; //meters
private float mass; //kilograms
```

because otherwise they are global (only one height and one mass would be supported among any number of `BMI` instances).

Answer (score 0):

`float` is not an object and even its object counterpart `Float` doesn't know this method `pow()`.
Try [Math.pow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29).